# Iterating Through TextBoxes to Check If Empty WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm attempting to iterate through all the textboxes in my WPF window to see if they are empty, and if they are, the method should set a bool to true.

```
private void checkTextBoxes(DependencyObject obj)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
   {
      if (obj is TextBox && ((TextBox)obj).Text == null)
      {
         isTextBoxEmpty = true;
      }
   }
}
```

`isTextBoxEmpty` is my bool that has been defined outside of the method. I call the method using:

```
checkTextBoxes(this);
```

But the bool always returns false no matter what I do, even if all the text boxes are empty.

Comment: If you're doing this for the sake of validation, there are better ways to achieve that. Have a look at [Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation).

Answer (score 0):

Outside of any syntax errors this should give you the result you expect; This only returns true if ALL textboxes are blank

```
private void checkTextBoxes(DependencyObject obj)
{
     var trueforall = true;
     var atleastone = false;
     for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
     {
         if (obj is TextBox)
         {
             if(!atleastone){ atleastone = true;}
             trueforall &= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((TextBox)obj).Text);
             if (!trueforall) { break; }
         }
     }
     isTextBoxEmpty = trueforall && atleastone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
((TextBox)obj).Text == null)
```

To this :

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty((TextBox)obj).Text))
```

The result you got **possibly** because `TextBox's Text` is never null, it is empty string (`""`) by default, thats what I think, just **possibly**.